# How to get index of changed item in angular form array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I'm using Angular 4 with reactive forms. I have a form array that I am trying to tie to an array I keep track of in my component. I'm using reactive forms so I can have the validation, so I don't want to use the template forms approach.

I add items to the form array like so:

```
createFormWithModel() {
  this.orderForm = this.fb.group({
    orderNumber: [this.order.ProductBookingOrder],
    orderDate: [this.order.PurchaseOrderIssuedDate],
    lineDetailsArray: this.fb.array([])
  })

  const arrayControl = <FormArray>this.orderForm.controls['lineDetailsArray'];
  this.order.ProductBookingDetails.forEach(item => {
    let newGroup = this.fb.group({
      ProductName: [item.ProductName],
      Quantity: [item.ProductQuantity.Quantity],
      UOM: [item.ProductQuantity.UOM],
      RequestedShipDate: [item.RequestedShipDate]
    })
  })
}
```

The orderForm is obviously my reactive forms FormGroup. the order is my object I get from my API and I want to update its values, including the line details. I think I should use 'valueChanges.subscribe' on each newGroup but I'm not sure how to get the index of the item that was changed. Any thoughts?

```
     newGroup.valueChanges.subscribe('i want value and index some how' => {
this.order.ProductbookingDetails[index].ProductName = value.ProductName;
    });
```

Here's the HTML for this portion:

```
<tbody formArrayName="lineDetailsArray">
        <tr [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let line of orderForm.controls['lineDetailsArray'].controls; index as i">
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Product Name" formControlName="ProductName" required/></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="number" step=".01" (focus)="$event.target.select()" placeholder="Quantity" formControlName="Quantity"/></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" readonly formControlName="UOM"></td>
          <td><date-picker formControlName="RequestedShipDate" format="L" [showClearButton]="false"></date-picker></td>
          <td><button type="button" (click)="deleteLineDetail(i)">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

Comment: why do you want save each line details? why can't you send total model

Comment: There is a ton of extra stuff I get my order model from the API, but I only want some of that stuff in the orderForm model. The orderForm model is just so that I can update the information that's allowed to be updated by the user. So I can't just send off the orderForm model to the API when things are done because it'll be missing all of the other information. I want my order model's values to be updated when the form inputs change

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would not use the `valueChanges` here, it would be fired excessively, specially if the array has many values.

You could have a change event on each value, and just pass the value and index, something like

```
(keyup)="changeValue(line.controls.ProductName.value, i)"
```

But this kind of fights the purpose of the reactive form.

Even though you have plenty of values that you do not want to show in form, and it is values that the user cannot modify, I'd just add them to the form anyway as form controls, nothing says that you need to show them in template!

This way, if you build the form in a way that it would match your model `order`, you could just directly assign the form value to your model upon submit. I highly recommend this approach.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, kind of. I cycled through each formArray control and rebuilt my line-detail and reassigned that new list to my order list of details. I'll try just straight up turning my form into my complex typescript object now. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Yeah, I think it's a good idea to just modify the form as such and get rid of having to capture the change events. In my opinion cleaner and more effective. Good luck, happy coding and have a great weekend! :)

Answer (score 14):

```
export class CustomFormArray {
     public form: FormGroup;

     public get someArray(): FormArray {
          return this.form.get('someArray') as FormArray;
     }

     constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
          this.form = _fb.group({
               someArray: _fb.array([])
          });

          this.someArray.controls.forEach(
               control => {
                   control.valueChanges.subscribe(
                        () => {
                       console.log(this.someArray.controls.indexOf(control)) // logs index of changed item in form array
                        }
                   )
               }
          )
     }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Please read why [it isn't wise to post code-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/341145)

Answer (score 1):

I found a method to help who wants to find the element that changes the value

Here is my html

```html
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Material</mat-label>
   <mat-select formControlName="material" (ngModelChange)="materialChange($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let objetct of materiais" [value]="objetct">   
        {{objetct?.nome}}
      </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is my Angular ts file

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-solicitar-material-form',
  templateUrl: './solicitar-material-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./solicitar-material-form.component.css']
})
export class SolicitarMaterialFormComponent implements OnInit {

  public form: FormGroup;
  private object: SolicitacaoMaterialDTO;
  public materiais: MaterialDTO[] = [];

  @Output() mudouValor: EventEmitter<Unidade> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      "itens": this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMateriais();
 }

  getMateriais() {
    this.materialService.findAll().subscribe((res) => {
      if (res) {
        this.materiais = res;
      }
    })
  }

  // this is the method that make me find the item that changed
  materialChange($event) {
    (<FormArray>this.form.get('itens')).controls.map((material) => {
      if (material.value.material == $event) {
        material.patchValue({
          unidadeMedida:$event.unidadeMedida
        });
      }
    });
  }

  get itens() {
    return this.form.get('itens') as FormArray;
  }

  clickAddItem() {
    this.itens.push(this.createItem());
  }

  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      material: this.formBuilder.control(null, [Validators.required]),
      unidadeMedida: this.formBuilder.control(null),
      quantidadeSolicitada: this.formBuilder.control(null, [Validators.required]),
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an own component for the items that you want to maintain in your form array. For every update, delete etc. you emit an event to the parent component and the index you can either emit with the event that you bind on in the parent component or you have the index in the parent component in the template too to use it as additional input parameter for the function that you use to bind on the change event of the child component.

Read through this article and you will understand what I mean:

https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular2-building-nested-reactive-forms-7978ecd145e4