# How to watch or listen to changes individually in form array in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
  constructor(private stockService: StockService, private fb: FormBuilder, public dialog: MatDialog, public snackBar: MatSnackBar, private supplierService: SupplierService, private productService: ProductService) { 
    this.stockForm = this.fb.group ({ //form validator for create and update
      _id: [ "" ],
      stockItem: this.fb.array([ this.createItem() ])
    });
  }


  createItem(): FormGroup { //form array for order Items
    return this.fb.group({
      supplierId: [ "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-f\d]{24}$/i), Validators.minLength(24), Validators.maxLength(24)]) ],
      productId: [ "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-f\d]{24}$/i), Validators.minLength(24), Validators.maxLength(24)]) ],
      productQuantity: [ "", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]\d*$/), Validators.min(1), Validators.max(99999)]) ]
    });
  }
```

i want to watch for the changes of individual element in form array. i have the code but it watches all form array for changes.

```
  onChanges(): void {
    this.stockForm.get('stockItem').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    });
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087222/how-to-get-index-of-changed-item-in-angular-form-array

Answer (score 0):

we can bind value changes like this :

1. Form Changes bind | Gonna call on any field value change

_

```
onChanges(): void {
  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    //DO you stuff
  });
}
```

2. Specific field binding | Gonna call on specific field change

_

```
onChanges(): void {
  this.myForm.get('FIELD_NAME').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {

  });
}
```

Hope this will help you. Also pass the field name instead of form name.

Comment: i have a formArray named 'stockItem' and one of the field inside it is 'supplierId', i want to listen on any changes only in supplier id

Comment: pass supplierId in option 2 and try.

Comment: this.stockForm.get('supplierId').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val);
    }); this is not working Error: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of null

Comment: You can try something like this.stockForm.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => { if (data.supplierId === 'someValue') { //do stuff } });